Why do I get the exception "javax/naming/NamingException" when executing "runDistributable" but only if the file logback.xml exists?
My goal: creating a running distributable KMP desktop application on Linux using logback.xml
Current issue: running the created distributable throws an exception if there is logback.xml file in the resource folder during creation of the distributable!
Environment

I created a sample project using the Kotlin Multiplatform Wizard and only selected "Desktop".
only change to the created project: adding and using kotlin-logging version 7.0
additionally added a simple logback.xml file in folder composeApp/src/commonMain/resources
the task "createDistributable" is running successfully
the task "runDistributable" fails with the following error message:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/naming/NamingException
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.ModelClassToModelHandlerLinker.link(ModelClassToModelHandlerLinker.java:57)
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator.addModelHandlerAssociations(JoranConfigurator.java:95)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericXMLConfigurator.processModel(GenericXMLConfigurator.java:215)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericXMLConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericXMLConfigurator.java:178)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericXMLConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericXMLConfigurator.java:123)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericXMLConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericXMLConfigurator.java:66)
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.DefaultJoranConfigurator.configureByResource(DefaultJoranConfigurator.java:68)
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.DefaultJoranConfigurator.configure(DefaultJoranConfigurator.java:35)
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.invokeConfigure(ContextInitializer.java:128)
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(ContextInitializer.java:103)
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(ContextInitializer.java:66)
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LogbackServiceProvider.initializeLoggerContext(LogbackServiceProvider.java:52)
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LogbackServiceProvider.initialize(LogbackServiceProvider.java:41)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:199)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:186)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getProvider(LoggerFactory.java:496)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:482)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:431)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:457)
        at com.samples.Greeting.<clinit>(Greeting.kt:10)
        at com.samples.ComposableSingletons$AppKt$lambda-3$1.invoke(App.kt:23)
        at com.samples.ComposableSingletons$AppKt$lambda-3$1.invoke(App.kt:22)
...

Content of build.gradle.kts in folder composeApp:
import org.jetbrains.compose.desktop.application.dsl.TargetFormat
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.ExperimentalKotlinGradlePluginApi
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.JvmTarget

plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinMultiplatform)
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrainsCompose)
    alias(libs.plugins.compose.compiler)
}

kotlin {
    androidTarget {
        @OptIn(ExperimentalKotlinGradlePluginApi::class)
        compilerOptions {
            jvmTarget.set(JvmTarget.JVM_22)
        }
    }
    
    jvm("desktop")
    
    sourceSets {
        val desktopMain by getting
        
        androidMain.dependencies {
            implementation(compose.preview)
            implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)
        }
        commonMain.dependencies {
            implementation(compose.runtime)
            implementation(compose.foundation)
            implementation(compose.material)
            implementation(compose.ui)
            implementation(compose.components.resources)
            implementation(compose.components.uiToolingPreview)
            implementation(libs.slf4j.api)
            implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel)
            implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.runtime.compose)
            implementation(libs.kotlin.logging)
        }
        desktopMain.dependencies {
            implementation(compose.desktop.currentOs)
            implementation(libs.kotlinx.coroutines.swing)
            runtimeOnly(libs.logback.core)
            runtimeOnly(libs.logback.classic)
        }
    }
}

android {
    namespace = "com.samples"
    compileSdk = libs.versions.android.compileSdk.get().toInt()

    sourceSets["main"].manifest.srcFile("src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml")
    sourceSets["main"].res.srcDirs("src/androidMain/res")
    sourceSets["main"].resources.srcDirs("src/commonMain/resources")

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.samples"
        minSdk = libs.versions.android.minSdk.get().toInt()
        targetSdk = libs.versions.android.targetSdk.get().toInt()
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        getByName("release") {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_22
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_22
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    dependencies {
        debugImplementation(compose.uiTooling)
    }
}

compose.desktop {
    application {
        mainClass = "com.samples.MainKt"

        nativeDistributions {
            targetFormats(TargetFormat.Dmg, TargetFormat.Msi, TargetFormat.Deb)
            packageName = "com.samples"
            packageVersion = "1.0.0"
        }
    }
}
...

When I do remove the logback.xml file the created distributable is running successfully.
However, I want to use the logback.xml to configure the log output.
Does anyone has any idea to solve this issue?
Many thanks in advance!

This issue was solved by adding additional modules to the distribution using the keyword "modules". See section "Configuring included JDK modules" in https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-multiplatform/blob/master/tutorials/Native_distributions_and_local_execution/README.md
